# Why does my sidebar module (with widget for product filtering) in wordpress divi builder not filtering my shop module

Tags: wordpress

I am using Product Filter by Nexter in my Wordpress (Divi Builder) website. It works perfectly with the default shop page of my website, but I encountered a problem when I make another page and add a SHOP Module and a SIDEBAR Module. The Sidebar in which I added a widget for product filtering does not filter my products in my SHOP Module.

I searched over the internet for solutions but nothing solved my problem. Or should I say, I really didn't have found a problem exactly the same with mine.

It looks like my SHOP Module and my SIDEBAR Module isn't connected with each other? I really don't know...

Here's a screenshot

[image]

It should not show the $25 tile :(

Comment: Help please? Thank you!

Comment: badly need solution :(